# How to add Media Buttons in Taskbar like VLC

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a Media Player and want to add Taskbar buttons like VLC. I tried some Extensions and Google Search but didn't find anything.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you read [Taskbar Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions) ? See the [Thumbnail Toolbars](Thumbnail Toolbars) section.

Comment: You can add Buttons (and related Icons) to a live preview thumbnail. IIRC, you should find this ~already implemented in the WindowsApiCodePack, Shell branch. A couple of more recent updates: [Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell 1.1.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft-WindowsAPICodePack-Shell/) and [WinCopies.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell 2.11.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinCopies.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell) (linked to [this GitHub](https://github.com/pierresprim/Windows-API-Code-Pack))

Comment: I tried but got this error whenever i debug my app. https://i.imgur.com/ZJuVM9b.png @Jimi

Comment: This is my code im using just for test and got error. `Private Sub PlayerForm_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        button1 = New ThumbnailToolBarButton(Me.Icon, "")
        TaskbarManager.Instance.ThumbnailToolBars.AddButtons(Me.Handle, button1)
    End Sub`